# Performance and Memory Consumption in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory-management

I have two question:

1) I need some expert view in terms of witting code which will be Performance and Memory Consumption wise sound enough.

2) Performance and Memory Consumption wise how good/bad is following piece of code and why ???

Need to increment the counter that could go maximum by 100 and writing code like this:

Some Sample Code is as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i=100;i++)
{
     Some Code
}

for(long i=0;i=1000;i++)
{
     Some Code
}
```

how good is to use Int16 or anything else instead of int, long if the requirement is same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Need to increment the counter that could go maximum by 100 and writing code like this:

Options given:

```
for(int i=0;i=100;i++)

for(long i=0;i=1000;i++)
```

EDIT: As noted, neither of these would even actually compile, due to the middle expression being an assignment rather than an expression of type `bool`.

This demonstrates a hugely important point: **get your code working before you make it fast**. Your two loops don't do the same thing - one has an upper bound of 1000, the other has an upper bound of 100. If you have to choose between "fast" and "correct", you almost *always* want to pick "correct". (There are exceptions to this, of course - but that's usually in terms of absolute correctness of results across large amounts of data, not *code* correctness.)

Changing between the variable types here is unlikely to make any measurable difference. That's often the case with micro-optimizations. When it comes to performance, architecture is usually *much* more important than in-method optimizations - and it's also a lot harder to change later on. In general, you should:

- Write the cleanest code you can, using types that represent your data most correctly and simply
- Determine reasonable performance requirements
- Measure your clean implementation
- *If* it doesn't perform well enough, use profiling etc to work out how to improve it

Comment: Actually, both loops do the same thing, because neither loop body will execute even once (we were talking about making the code correct, after all).

Comment: In fact this code won't work at all, because loop condition won't be true at the first run (and more of that, is not even a condition).

Comment: i just wanna to know in a big project where architecture is the key, then what could be the best plan....

Comment: @Sham: That's far too broad a question to really answer here. Consider where your bottlenecks would be, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;


for(int i=0;i=10000;i++)
{
     Some Code
}

response.write ((DateTime.Now - dtStart).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

same way for Long as well and you can know which one is better... ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing things that require a number representing iterations, or the quantity of something, you should always use `int` unless you have a good *semantic* reason to use a different type (ie data can never be negative, or it could be bigger than 2^31).  Additionally, Worrying about this sort of nano-optimization concern will basically never matter when writing c# code.

That being said, if you are wondering about the differences between things like this (incrementing a 4 byte register versus incrementing 8 bytes), you can always cosult Mr. Agner's wonderful [instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

On an Amd64 machine, incrementing `long` takes the same amount of time as incrementing `int`.**

On a 32 bit x86 machine, incrementing `int` will take less time.

** The same is true for almost all logic and math operations, as long as the value is not both memory bound and unaligned.  In .NET a `long` will always be aligned, so the two will always be the same.